# Ionic Angular doesn't work on Android devices

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm facing a Ionic Framework problem for 2 days. I dont know why my controller was not found by my device. I have other Ionic projects who work perfectly. Can someone help-me ?

I'm calling my controller by ng-controller on  tag, and my ng-app on body. Then, I configured on my app.js the outside modules and next my controller.js with the button functions. This code works perfectly on browser, but on Android devices, his not execute any of those angularjs directives.

My app.js

```js
var app = angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'ionic-datepicker', 'ion-floating-menu', 'ionic-timepicker']);

app.run(function ($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function () {
    if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);
    }
    if (window.StatusBar) {
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }
  });
})

app.config(function (ionicTimePickerProvider) {
  var timePickerObj = {
    inputTime: (((new Date()).getHours() * 60 * 60) + ((new Date()).getMinutes() * 60)),
    format: 24,
    step: 10,
    setLabel: 'Set',
    closeLabel: 'Close'
  };
  ionicTimePickerProvider.configTimePicker(timePickerObj);
})

app.config(function (ionicDatePickerProvider) {
  var datePickerObj = {
    inputDate: new Date(),
    titleLabel: 'Selecione a data',
    setLabel: 'OK',
    todayLabel: 'Hoje',
    closeLabel: 'Fechar',
    mondayFirst: false,
    weeksList: ["Dom", "Seg", "Ter", "Quar", "Quin", "Sex", "Sab"],
    monthsList: ["Janeiro", "Fevereiro", "Março", "Abril", "Maio", "Junho", "Julho", "Agosto", "Setembro", "Outubro", "Novembro", "Dezembro"],
    templateType: 'popup',
    from: new Date(2012, 8, 1),
    to: new Date(2018, 8, 1),
    showTodayButton: true,
    dateFormat: 'dd MMMM yyyy',
    closeOnSelect: false,
    disableWeekdays: []
  };
  ionicDatePickerProvider.configDatePicker(datePickerObj);
})

app.controller('mainController', function ($scope, $ionicPopup, $timeout, $ionicListDelegate,
  ionicDatePicker, ionicTimePicker, $interval) {

  //Task Recebe a Model taskModel
  var tasks = new getTask();

  $scope.dias = 0;
  $scope.horas = 0;
  $scope.minutos = 0;
  $scope.segundos = 0;
  $scope.fullTime = {};
  $scope.taskDate = '';
  $scope.taskTime = {
    horas: "",
    minutos: ""
  };
  var data = $scope.taskTime;
  $scope.lista = tasks.items;
  $scope.showMarket = false;
  $scope.removeStatus = false;
  $scope.plusHide = false;

  $scope.marcarTarefa = function (item) {
    item.finalizada = !item.finalizada;
  };

  $scope.click = function () {
    console.log($scope.showMarket);
  };

  $scope.onHideItem = function (item) {
    return item.finalizada && $scope.showMarket;
  };

  $scope.onItemRemove = function (item) {
    tasks.remove(item);
    tasks.save();
  };

  $scope.onControlShow = function () {
    $scope.removeStatus = !$scope.removeStatus;
    $scope.plusHide = !$scope.plusHide;
  };

  function conveterTempo(item) {

    var _second = 1000;
    var _minute = _second * 60;
    var _hour = _minute * 60;
    var _day = _hour * 24;
    var timer;

    var now = new Date().getTime();
    console.log(now);
    var timeRest = new Date(item.date).getTime();
    console.log(timeRest);
    var distance = timeRest - now;
    console.log(distance);


    var days = Math.floor(distance / _day);
    $scope.dias = days;
    var hours = Math.floor((distance % _day) / _hour);
    $scope.horas = hours;
    var minutes = Math.floor((distance % _hour) / _minute);
    $scope.minutos = minutes;
    var seconds = Math.floor((distance % _minute) / _second);
    $scope.segundos = seconds;
  };

  //Função de click do relógio
  $scope.onItemClick = function (item) {

    conveterTempo(item);

    $ionicPopup.show({
      title: "Tempo restante",
      scope: $scope,
      template: "Data a ser entregue: " + item.date + "<p>Hora de entrega: " +
      item.time.horas + " : " + item.time.minutos + "</p>" + "<br>" 
      + "Faltam: " +$scope.dias + " - dias <br>" +$scope.horas+" horas "+ $scope.minutos + " minutos " + $scope.segundos,
      buttons: [{
        text: "Ok",
      }, {
        text: "Cancelar"
      },]
    });
    $ionicListDelegate.closeOptionButtons();
  }
  //Fim da função do clique ----->


  //Função acionada ao click no campo de input da data
  $scope.openDatePicker = function () {
    //Recebe a data do datepicker e passa para o escopo
    var getData = {
      callback: function (val) {
        $scope.taskDate = new Date(val).toDateString();
      },
    };
    ionicDatePicker.openDatePicker(getData);
  };


  $scope.openTimePicker = function () {
    //Recebe a data do datepicker e passa para o escopo
    var getTime = {
      callback: function (val) {
        if (typeof (val) === 'undefined') {
          console.log('Time not selected');
        } else {
          var selectedTime = new Date(val * 1000);

          $scope.taskTime = {
            horas: selectedTime.getUTCHours(),
            minutos: selectedTime.getUTCMinutes()
          };

          $scope.taskTime.full = $scope.taskTime.horas + " : " + $scope.taskTime.minutos;

        };
      },
    };
    ionicTimePicker.openTimePicker(getTime);
  };

  $scope.fullTime = function (data) {
    if (data.horas === '') {
      console.log("Ainda não possui tempo definido.")
    } else {
      console.log("Horas: " + data.horas);
      console.log("Minutos: " + data.minutos);
      return data.horas + ":" + data.minutos;
    }
  };




  $scope.onItemAdd = function () {
    var item = {
      nome: '',
      finalizada: true,
      date: '',
      time:
      {
        horas: '',
        minutos: ''
      }
    };
    getItem(item, true);
  };

  function getItem(item, novo) {
    $scope.data = {};
    $scope.time = {};
    $scope.data.newTask = item.nome;

    $ionicPopup.show({
      title: "Nova tarefa",
      scope: $scope,
      template: "<input type='text' placeholder='Nova tarefa...' autofocus ='true' ng-model='data.newTask'>" +
      "<input type='text' placeholder='Selecione a data de conclusão' ng-model='taskDate' ng-click='openDatePicker()' />" +
      "<input type='text' placeholder='Selecione a hora de conclusão' ng-model='taskTime.full' ng-init='taskTime.full = fullTime(taskTime)'  ng-click='openTimePicker()'>",
      buttons: [{
        text: "Ok",
        onTap: function (e) {

          item.nome = $scope.data.newTask;
          item.date = $scope.taskDate;
          item.time.horas = $scope.taskTime.horas;
          item.time.minutos = $scope.taskTime.minutos;
          if (novo) {
            tasks.add(item);
          };
          tasks.save();
        }
      }, {
        text: "Cancelar"
      },]
    });
    $ionicListDelegate.closeOptionButtons();
  };

  $scope.onItemEdit = function (item) {
    getItem(item, false);
  };

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
 <title>TaskFC</title>
 <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">

 <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>

 <link href="css/ion-floating-menu.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <script src="lib/angular-timer/angular-timer.min.js"></script>
 <script src="lib/floating-menu/ion-floating-menu.min.js"></script>
 <script src="js/taskModel.js"></script>
 <script src="cordova.js"></script>
 <script src="js/app.js"></script>
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
 <script src="lib/ionic-datepicker/dist/ionic-datepicker.bundle.min.js"></script>
 <script src="lib/ionic-timepicker/dist/ionic-timepicker.bundle.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body ng-app="starter">

 <ion-pane ng-controller="mainController">
  <ion-header-bar class="bar-positive">
   <!--<button class="button button-icon icon ion-navicon"></button>-->
   <h1 class="title">Lista de tarefas</h1>
   <button class="button button-icon icon ion-settings" ng-click="onControlShow()"></button>
  </ion-header-bar>
  </div>
  <ion-content>
   <ion-list show-delete="removeStatus">
    <ion-item ng-repeat="item in lista track by $index" ng-hide="onHideItem(item)">
     <!--especificando a propriedade do item buscada-->
     <div class="row">
      <div class="col col-50">
       <div class="item-icon-right" ng-click="onItemClick(item)">
        {{item.nome}}
        <i class="icon ion ion-android-time"></i>
       </div>
       <ion-delete-button class="ion-minus-circled" ng-click="onItemRemove(item)"></ion-delete-button>
       <ion-option-button class="button-positive" ng-click="onItemEdit(item)">Editar</ion-option-button>
      </div>
      <div class="col">


      </div>
      <div class="col">
       <button class="button button-positive button-small button-outline" ng-click="marcarTarefa(item)">
                         <i class="ion ion-checkmark" ng-show="!item.finalizada"></i>
                        </button>
      </div>
     </div>
    </ion-item>
   </ion-list>
   <div style="text-align:center; font-size:10px;">Icons made by <a href="http://www.flaticon.com/authors/madebyoliver" title="Madebyoliver">Madebyoliver</a> from <a href="http://www.flaticon.com"
     title="Flaticon">www.flaticon.com</a> is licensed by <a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0/" title="Creative Commons BY 3.0"
     target="_blank">CC 3.0 BY</a></div>
  </ion-content>

  <ion-footer-bar class="bar-positive">
   <div class="row row-center">
    <div class="col col-90">
     <div class="buttons">
      <button class="button button-clear button-light">Finalizadas</button>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="10">
     <label class="toggle toggle-light toggle-small">
                     <input type="checkbox" ng-model="showMarket" />
                       <div class="track">
                      <div class="handle"></div>
                   </div>
                </label>
    </div>
   </div>
  </ion-footer-bar>
  <div class="row responsive-sm">
   <ion-floating-button ng-click="onItemAdd()" ng-show="plusHide" has-footer="true" button-color="#EF473A" icon="ion-plus" icon-color="#fff">
   </ion-floating-button>
  </div>
 </ion-pane>
</body>

</html>
```

My taskModel.js

```
//Rarray de itens
```

function getTask() {
    this.items = [];

```
var lista = localStorage.getItem("tasklist");

if(lista !== null) 
{
 this.items = angular.fromJson(lista);
};

this.save = function () {
    var lista = angular.toJson(this.items);
    localStorage.setItem("tasklist", lista);
};

this.remove = function (item) {
    var pos = this.items.indexOf(item);
    this.items.splice(pos, 1);
};

this.add = function (item) {
    this.items.push(item);
};
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Took your code to Ionic Playground, the error occurs here:

```
//Task Recebe a Model taskModel
var tasks = new getTask();
```

`getTask` is not defined in your code. So your controller throws an error directly when initiating.

[Here's the Playground example](http://play.ionic.io/app/b6e29b1e565a), in case you want to play around with it. ;)

Comment: Wow, thank you OClyde, i did not know this Playground, so useful OMG! I'm Trying to make work cleared my controller and my html, to use an simple calling function using ng-click() but still doesn't work. :(

Comment: Have you checked the console? Any errors thrown? Otherwise just save the playground and post it here so I can have a look later :)

Comment: There is no error on console here. :( http://play.ionic.io/app/4de8b75fa15f

Comment: Will have a look at it as soon as possible!

Comment: Thank you, I'll be waiting.

Comment: Had a look at your solution and have to say - can't really get the idea behind this! Could you explain what's your expected behaviour? EDIT: To be more detailed: Not sure how you want to add an item to the list right now. Can't wrap my head around this scenario. ;)